# Grease Pencil Object disappears in Compositing

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, grease-pencil

I've added a denoise node to my compositing set-up, and ever since my grease pencil object no longer renders. I can see it in the rendering process, but after the compositing step, it disappears:

[image: Before compositing, Grease Pencil visible]

[image: After compositing, Grease Pencil has disappeared]

First image is a screenshot taken just after the render finished. Second image is a couple seconds after, once compositing is done.

Here is my node set-up:

[image]

And here is my file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qikMqL0qLM8kCeVBX4qdQyrz7lVV0P9U/view?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: Please upload your blend file here, so it will always be available in the future:
https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i can reproduce this, the noisy image output doesn't include the greasepencil, might be a bug. Then, I might be missing something but i don't see why you do this in comp, cos just enabling denoise in the render settings gives you the same image and includes GP